# Extract graph def from model.ckpt.meta

Tags: python, tensorflow

How would I go about generating a `graph.pbtxt`, i.e. a protobuf containing the graph def, from a metagraphdef file like `model.ckpt.meta`?

I guess that both files, `graph.pbtxt` and `model.ckpt.meta` are generated during training. However, I want to use an analysis tool that requires a `graph.pbtxt` on a pre-trained NN of which I only have access to the `model.ckpt.*` files.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To generate a protobuf you need two things:

- The metagraph, the `.meta` that you mention,
- The checkpoint, `.ckpt` that is generated alongside.

Essentially, the `.meta` file contains the graph definition while the `.ckpt` contains the weights of the trained model. The protobuf format merges the two in one file.

You have to load the meta graph and then the checkpoint as follow:

```
sess = tf.Session()
saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph(meta_file)
saver.restore(save_path=ckpt_file, sess=sess)
```

Finally, you have to define the output nodes of your graph before exporting it to the protobuf format. The output nodes consist in a list of names of the output layers you would like to be able to retrieve. For instance it could be `['myModel/fc12/BiasAdd']`.

```
from tensorflow.python.framework import graph_util

output_graph = graph_util.convert_variables_to_constants(
    sess,
    sess.graph.as_graph_def(),
    output_node_names)

with tf.gfile.GFile('output.pb', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(output_graph.SerializeToString())
```

Comment: Thank you for the insight :) FYI I found a similar solution while you were replying, which involves writing the graph in .pbtxt without weights, using `tf.train.write_graph(sess.graph_def, ".", "graph.pbtxt", True)`, and then using the freeze_graph tool to convert the variables to constants.